# DNS Manager Windows 2003 godaddy

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, godaddy

I have the domain "solinkcorp.com" registered with Go Daddy.

I want to point it to our internal web server so that we can manage the DNS. I have created two names servers "ns1.solinkcorp.com" and "ns2.solinkcorp.com"...both work and resolve to the correct IP.

How do I make solinkcorp.com resolve to the correct IP?? right now it can't be pinged. I have tried creating a new forward lookup zone for solinkcorp but it is not working. Is this the right step? every time I add A records to ns1 or ns2...it creates one for demo.ns1.solinkcorp.com...i want to remove the ns1.

I also need to setup email using MX recoreds,..but I assume once solinkcorp.com resolves that will work.

Any guidance at all will be appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind...needed some time to propagate through...(20 min)